# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Input.ICommand' to 'Xamarin.Forms.Command'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In XAML I am doing the following:

```
<template:GridTemplate GridType="2" 
     Text="Answer Visible" Label="{Binding AtiLabel}" 
     TapCommand="{Binding OpenPageCmd }" 
     TapCommandParam="Answer Visible" />
```

and in C# I do this:

```
var cell = new GridTemplate {
       BindingContext = row,
       GridType = "2",
       Text = row.Name,
       Label = "X",
       TapCommand = vm.OpenPageCmd,
       TapCommandParam = "Category"
};
```

But in C# it gives me this error:

> Cards.DetailsSection.cs(34,34): Error CS0266: Cannot implicitly
>   convert type 'System.Windows.Input.ICommand' to
>   'Xamarin.Forms.Command'. An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?) (CS0266)

Can someone suggest a solution and tell me why this might be happening?

```
private ICommand openPageCmd;
public ICommand OpenPageCmd => openPageCmd ?? (openPageCmd = new Command<string>((pageType) => settingsPage.OpenPage(pageType)));
```

Comment: Explicitly convert the interface to a concrete type: `TapCommand = vm.OpenPageCmd as Command,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a couple of things. Change your `ICommand` into a concrete `Command`:

```
private Command openPageCmd;
public Command OpenPageCmd => openPageCmd ?? (openPageCmd = new Command<string>((pageType) => settingsPage.OpenPage(pageType)));
```

Or have your `template:GridTemplate` expect an `ICommand` if it is a control you created. Lastly, you could cast the `OpenPageCmd` command explicitly: `TapCommand = (Command)vm.OpenPageCmd,`.